# What do I need to do to get the UIImagePickerController working with swift in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a swift app that has a photo picker and the app is landscape only. I get the following error when I try to open the picker

> exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason:
>   'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the
>   application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is
>   returning YES'

I know the picker wants to pick portrait and in objective C the fix was to create the category and add the shouldAutorotate and set it to yes (I have a working example of this). And I understand in Swift categories are now extensions.

So I tried to write an extension for the picker and my UIViewcontroller but that did not fix it.

What do I need to do to get the UIImagePickerController working with swift in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the next tutorial for resize classes from apple:
http://swiftiostutorials.com/using-size-classes-xcode-6/
You just need to design your app fpr the two cases, portrait and landscape.

Comment: But I don't want the 2 cases. I want landscape only. And I need to get the image picker to be landscape (else it crashes). I can do this in objective-c but need to figure out how to do it in swift.

Comment: Then go the the settings menu of the xcode project and select Device Orientation: Landscape Left and Landscape Right